# Module 'react-navigation' doesn't exist in the haste module map

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm facing the problem as "react-navigation is not exist in the haste module map" eventhough I've installed "react-navigation" and "react-native-gesture-handler"

```
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
} from 'react-navigation'

const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
  SplashScreen: { screen: SplashScreen },
  MainScreen: { screen: MainScreen },
  AddExpenseScreen: { screen: AddExpenseScreen },
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'SplashScreen',
  headerMode: 'none'
})

const App = createAppContainer(RootStack)

Package.json
------------
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.9",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^3.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6"
  },
```

Comment: Try by removing node_modules and reinstall it,

remove node_modules and reinstalled.
run react-native start --reset-cahce or npm start -- --reset-cache
removed haste-map* directories from '/tmp`
removed metro-bundler-cache-*
cleared watchman

Comment: I've tried already. Still the same issue persisting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your package.json, it says "react-native-navigation", but you're importing from "react-navigation".

Make sure to follow the instructions properly https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html

Answer (score -1):

Instead of :

```
const App = createAppContainer(RootStack)
```

Try :

```
export default createAppContainer(RootStack);
```

Check [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html#creating-a-stack-navigator) for details.